# Improve SOAP UI performance

Tags: web-services, soapui

I've started using SOAP UI recently to test web services and it's pretty cool, but it's a huge resource hog.

Is there any way to reduce the amount of resources it uses?

Comment: Check out our new Runscope Radar automated API testing service.

Comment: try locust.io which serve both load and api test purpose.

Comment: You can check the following article that discusses SOAPUI alternatives:
[5 Best SOAPUI alternative applications](http://techonestop.com/soapui-alternative-for-webservice-testing).
I assume majority of them (probably all) support Windows OS.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be a resource hog, although I've seen it do this before. I leave it running on my PC all week, and a co-worker with a similar machine (dual-core running XP) has to kill it every few hours, otherwise it keeps using CPU.  I'd try uninstalling/re-installing.  Currently, my instance has been up for 10 days, running a mockservice that I've been hitting very hard (I've sent it thousands of requests).  CPU time total (over 10 days) is about an hour and a half, but the "right now" number is about 1%.

There are no popular alternatives, aside from writing your own client in the language of your choice.

Comment: Disabling the browser component (`-Dsoapui.jxbrowser.disable=true`) solved the 100% CPU usage issues for me. (when it was enabled, it periodically went to 100% CPU even when not running any tests/requests). Just throwing it out here, maybe it's useful for others, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you're testing `WCF services`, you can run `wcftestclient` from the `Visual Studio command line`.  It works for local or remotely hosted services.  Its no good for `ASMX-style .NET 2.0 SOAP` services though.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was down-voted.  WCFTestClient is not a complete replacement for SoapUI, but if the SOAP service happens to be hosted by WCF then WCFTestClient is not an unreasonable client to look into for light-weight testing.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to test using only json, you could use some of the light weight Rest clients ex. Mozilla Rest plugin.

Answer (score 1):

We test our SOAP APIs manually with SOAP UI and otherwise use jMeter for automated SOAP API testing. While having a GUI seems attractive first, I find both applications quiet user-unfriendly and time consuming to work with.

As already suggested, you could do it in code using Java or maybe use a dynamic language like Ruby:
[Testing SOAP Webservices with RSpec](http://geekiriki.blogspot.nl/2010/11/testing-soap-webservices-with-rspec.html)
[SOAP web Services testing in RUBY](http://agileqatesting.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/soap-web-services-testing-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 0):

As user mitchnull mentions in his comment:

> Disabling the browser component (-Dsoapui.jxbrowser.disable=true)
>   solved the 100% CPU usage issues for me. (when it was enabled, it
>   periodically went to 100% CPU even when not running any
>   tests/requests).